# Error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*', when header contains "withCredentials" with request

Tags: angular, cookies

I am sending a request from angular to my server with header `withCredentials` as `true` and on server side i have only allowed request from origin `http://0.0.0.0:4200` where my angular is running. Since my request contains authorizaion header it sends **preflight request** and it fails with below error message.
[image: Error message]

But if you will look at my response of **preflight** request there is no wildcard in the value of header **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"**.

Preflight response:

[image: Preflight response headers]

Method in angular :

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders(credentials ? {
      authorization : 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.username + ':' + credentials.password)
  } : {});
  headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:4200")
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user', {headers: headers , withCredentials: true }).subscribe(response => {..}
```

Can someone please explain me why i am getting this error and how to fix it?

**SErver side code :-**

**CORSfilter.java**

```
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization,withCredentials, content-type, xsrf-token, Cache-Control, Cookie");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

**SpringSecurityConfig class**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
        http
        .httpBasic()
      .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
          .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());;
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class SecurityController {

    @GetMapping("/hi")
    public Response method() {
        return new Response("Hi this is resposne from hi");
    }

    @GetMapping("/hi2")
    public Response method2() {
        return new Response("Hi this is resposne from hi2");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you find a solution? i have the same problem with jwt cookies + angular + springboot

Answer (score 1):

try to add this on server side near"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" setting：

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `CORS` is not enabled on your server.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin. A web application makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin.

So whenever a javascript code wants to send a request to another origin, It can only be via the allowed origin resources. This resources are provided in response header of server.

So if server doesn't allow any request from origins outside of his scope, they all will be failed. Because browser doesn't allow it to happen.

So enable `CORS` on your server side, so that angular can interact with it outside of server scope.

Comment: it is enabled i am getting this error only  when i add  header `withCredentials` with request. if i remove that header it works. intially it was disabled so i was getting  CORS error ,after enabling error went but now when i am adding this header im getting this error

Comment: No it's not enabled. your server is on 8080 port but you are requesting from 4200 port, So the origin is different. `CORS` is not enable correctly on your server.

Comment: my origin has to be `http://localhost:4200` right? can you please read the complete errror message it says CORS policy failed b'cos i am using that header

Comment: set it for a test to `*` and see how it goes? `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: it was `*` before and it was working..but once i added  header `withCredentials` it said origin can't be wildcard it has to be specific bcos i have that header in request

Comment: wait a minute? did you set cors headers in your client angular request? No you should set it your server side